# How to add row to MS Access table which linked to another tables?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I have MS Access database (I have to use Access) with this structure (names barely traslated for this question):

[image]

My programm allow to add row to each table. To work with database I use `OleDbDataAdapter`. This code successfully add row to "desease":

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " 
    + "desease (title, description) VALUES (?, ?)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", "input text");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", "input text");
adapter.InsertCommand = command;
adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

But I also need to do same to "visits" table. Well, I try this:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Посещения " + 
    "(patient ID, doctor ID, desease ID, visit date) " + 
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("patient ID", "1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("doctor ID", "1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("desease ID", "1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("visit date", "01.05.1999");
adapter.InsertCommand = command;
adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

And get error: `syntax error in instruction INSERT INTO`.

So what is right command for "visits"? What datatypes i have to send to parameters? And especially for IDs. In database they have number type (in translation it called so). `Visit date` is also have `date` type

I can't find any info about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your column names contains more than one word, you need to them in a square brackets like `[patient ID]`, `[doctor ID]`, `[desease ID]` and `[visit date]`

As a best practice, change their names to one word.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` methods manually.

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    commmand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Посещения([patient ID],[doctor ID], [desease ID], [visit date])
                             VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("patient ID", "1");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("doctor ID", "1");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("desease ID", "1");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("visit date", "01.05.1999");

    adapter.InsertCommand = command;
    connection.Open();
    adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Based on your column names, I think your first 3 column should be numeric type instead of character and the last one should be better for `DATETIME` type.

Comment: Great! Now i can do it in the right way. Thanks again.